# Sending email with body as HTML in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

The below code snippet shares the content to gmail from the Android App.
The HTML formatting is lost. Some of the text has color and underlining propery.
These properties are lost once the data is passed to email app.

How can I send the text with colors, font size, etc as body in email?

```
        Intent eIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    eIntent.setType("text/html");
    eIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    eIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + ""));
    eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            new String[] { recipientMailId });
    eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    eIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Utils.formatHtmlText("<html><body><h1 style=\"background-color:DodgerBlue;\">Hello World</h1><p style=\"background-color:Tomato;\">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><p style=\"color:#FF0000\";>Red paragraph text</p><p><b>This text is bold</b></p><p><i>This text is italic</i></p><p>This is<sub> subscript</sub> and <sup>superscript</sup></p><h2>How to Change Font Size Within the Same Paragraph [Inline CSS]</h2><p>This is dummy text. This is more dummy text. <span style=\"font-size: 26px\">This is larger text.</span> This is more dummy text. This is more dummy text. This is more dummy text. This is more dummy text. This is more dummy text.</p><h3>The Explanation</h3><p>The default font size is 16px. Changing the font size of a paragraph will require me to use a style attribute that contains the CSS font-size property set to \"26px.\" The other elements on the page are not targeted by inline CSS and therefore remain 16px.</p><p>DLF stands for <u>Delhi Land and Finance </u>.<br> Delhi Land and Finance is one of the largest commercial real estate developer in India.</p></body></html>"));
    return eIntent;
```

Comment: There is no requirement for Gmail, or any mail client, to offer an email composer with an editor window that supports arbitrary HTML. Have your app send the data, or the full HTML, to your secure Web service, and it can send the email.